# Invalid column name on adapter fill

Tags: c#, sql

I am getting a System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException with additional information of an Invalid column name Jun on Fill function while I am entering 19-jun-2016 from the datetimePicker and here is a Jun is a month but it taking it as a column.

ReportForm.cs

```
public void MakeDailyReport(string givenDate, DataGridView view)
{
    con.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Date FROM FinalSales where Date = @datePicker", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datePicker", givenDate);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    DateTime dateObject = (DateTime)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    string dateObjectstring = Convert.ToString(dateObject.ToShortDateString());
    string givenDateString = Convert.ToString(givenDate);

    if (dateObjectstring == givenDateString)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Date FROM FinalSales where Date = " + givenDate + "", con);
        if (adapt != null)
        {
            adapt.Fill(dt);

            view.DataSource = dt;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Record found againts that date");
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `givenDate`?  It would appear to not be valid SQL code in that context.  You can likely avoid the problem entirely by treating it as a parameter value instead of as executable SQL code.

Comment: In your first query you used a parameter while in the second one you used a string concatenation. The error is expected.

Comment: Why you need for a query here? `Date FROM FinalSales where Date = "+givenDate+""` you are selecting Date from a table and your condition is `Date=X;` the output will also be the same as that in the where condition

Comment: @un-lucky: Even better, nothing is ever done with the *result* of that (well, the first) query.  He then goes on to convert a string to a string for some reason as well.  There is *a lot* wrong with this code :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use string concatenation to build your query but sql parameters with the correct type. That will also prevent you from sql injection and other possible issues (like this one).

```
adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [Date] FROM FinalSales where [Date] = @givenDate", con);
var dateParameter = adapt.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@givenDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
dateParameter.Value = dateTimePicker.Value.Date;  // not string but the correct type DateTime
```

Note that i've also used `dateTimePicker.Value.Date` to ignore the time portion.

Comment: thanks its work but i am not getting any output the data in SQL is "2016-06-19" and the other date is "16-Jun-2016". how can i fix it.

Comment: @HassaanSohail: Well, those are different dates.  The `=` operator is looking for values which are the same, not values which are different.  Based on the description, it also seems like you might be mixing up types here.  If you're using strings instead of actual date and/or time values then it becomes your responsibility to consistently format those date/time strings.  That's generally a responsibility you don't want.  Use actual `Date` values, not strings.

Comment: @David Can u give me example in your above solution.

Comment: @HassaanSohail: as David said, your confusing types. Don't fiddle around with strings when you want to filter by datetime. Maybe you have to use `dateTimePicker.Value.Date` to omit the time portion of the datetimepicker.value. I've edited my answer accordingly.